# Is there a way to see the number of promises in the event loop?

Tags: javascript, deno

Basically like the title says, is there a way to see how many promises currently exist within the event loop from within the JavaScript program? Preferably on Deno.

Comment: A promise does not 'exist in the event loop', the event loop is the handler of the task queue. So I'm not sure what you're asking. A promise may be unresolved without its callback being in the task queue, so the answer you're looking for is probably the count how many promises are yet unresolved? A simple solution would be to add a global counter that you increment when creating a promise and decrement in the resolve/error callback. Then you should know how many promises are currently left unresolved.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: Frame challenge: What do you call a Promise and what makes them special? Remember that not only Promise instances are thenable, and that not only thenables can produce microtasks.

Comment: I guess is that OP is dealing with code that doesn't properly cleanup / has potential leaks and they want a way to (quantitatively) confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deno v1.26 added an **internal** API that can be used to track promises.

```js
Deno.core.setPromiseHooks(init, before, after, resolve);
```

```js
Deno.core.setPromiseHooks(
    // init
    (promise, parentPromise) => {
      console.log('init', promise, parentPromise);
    },
    // before
    promise => {},
    // after
    promise => {},
    // resolve
    promise => {
        console.log(promise, 'resolved');
    }
);
```

For a detailed usage check the following Deno test:

https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/main/cli/tests/unit/promise_hooks_test.ts

**NOTE:** The API is undocumented and may change in the future.